# define a new home page to sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

I realized a simple  interface for my sub SharePoint site. but I have no idea how I download my files Interface (Javasript, css, html) that index.html becomes my homepage on my website .
best regards

Answer (score 0):

Upload all files to a document library, then use SharePoint Designer to set index.html as the home page.

http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/09/05/how-to-set-a-page-as-home-page-in-sharepoint-2013-site/

Edit: If you want SharePoint functionality, then you need to do what we all do: Use a SharePoint page and customize it to show/hide what you want to see. In many cases, custom CSS can be used to hide unwanted SharePoint elements. Custom HTML can be applied by editing an individual page.

Second edit: It seems that you have very sparse understanding of SharePoint and what it can do. You need to learn how SharePoint works. It's way more than just html and it's WAAAAY more than can be posted in an answer here. No way around that. Get clued up about what SharePoint does before you do things with it that it does not do naturally.

Comment: it works thank you but  I want that the top  Rubon  appears in my page  .where there are the information of sessions .

Comment: Then don't use an HTML page. Use a regular SharePoint ASPX page that is governed by the master page and contains the SharePoint elements.

Comment: OK . i creat a new share point page but i want to personalize my page like hide the  menu at left ; add the code of my html interface.

Comment: I updated my answer. Use CSS and edit the page to add your html.

Comment: but when i edit a sharepoint page with  share point designer i can't found the html code or css i found just the share point balise .

Comment: You need to learn how SharePoint works. It's way more than just html and it's WAAAAY more than can be posted in an answer here. No way around that. Get clued up about what SharePoint does before you do things with it that it does not.